# How to prove this relation?

Tags: limits, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

Is the relation $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{Q_n^m(x)}{P_n^m(x)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\cot m\pi$$ correct? Here ***P*** and ***Q*** are the [associated Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials) of the first and [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function) kind respectively. Does anybody know how to prove it, or some references that I can refer to?
How about the limit at $x\rightarrow -1$? Is there a relation
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -1}\frac{Q_n^m(x)}{P_n^m(x)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\cot n\pi~?$$

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to be a physics question.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definitions of the Ferrers functions [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/14.3), we have

$$\frac{Q_\nu^\mu(z)}{P_\nu^\mu(z)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\cot(\pi\mu )-\csc(\pi\mu)\frac{\Gamma(\nu +\mu +1)}{\Gamma (\nu -\mu +1)}\frac{\Gamma(1-\mu)}{\Gamma(1+\mu)}\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^{\mu }\frac{_2F_1\left({{-\nu,1+\nu}\atop{1+\mu}}\mid\frac{1-z}{2}\right)}{_2F_1\left({{-\nu ,1+\nu}\atop{1-\mu}}\mid\frac{1-z}{2}\right)}\right)$$

Letting $z=1$ proves the identity in the OP.